# How do I pass a full string to batch?

Tags: c++, batch-file

I am writing a C++ program that lets me search Wikipedia, Google, Wolfram Alpha, etc. I'm doing this by asking for the input (what I want to search with such as "Pictures of Cats") and I pass that input to batch where it runs a command to open a google search using my input. Here's what it looks like:

```
string input;
cout<<"What do you want to search?"<<endl;
getline(cin, input, '\n');
system(("START https://www.google.com/search?q="+input).c_str());
```

The problem is, if I ask it to search for "Funny cats", it only searches for Funny. What should I do? I'm also open to suggestions of other ways to do this, other than using cmd.

Comment: Why Did You Start Every Word With A Capital? It Is Completely Unnecessary, And Looks Awful.

Comment: I _think_ you will need to URL encode the `input`.

Comment: Please, please, please don't use `system`. You are asking for a lot of pain using that.

Comment: If the argument string has a space in it you need to enclose it in quotation marks or the command shell won't see the whole string as a single argument.

Comment: What URL do you see if you search for multiple words manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Url-encode the search string: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding